# Model or Library class

Tags: php, model-view-controller, email, authentication, model

Im going to do an Email class for sending emails in my MVC framework.
I also have a login class that just checks if the user is in the database.

Should I put those classes in the library folder or should I implement them as models?

I tried to do search but couldnt find straight answer..

Comment: what is the login class for. it should be a method on the user model

Comment: haha right after I posted this I started to think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO mailer classes are similar two controllers. They should fetch the data from a model and than render a view (email).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [reference](http://www.zendcasts.com/painless-html-emails-with-zend_mail/2010/06/) and see if it helps you.

Comment: It seems like its positioned in the library.

Comment: Yes, but it uses Zend View to render, so logically it's a controller